Can I pass extra arguments into the panda to_sql method callable?
I've been looking at the Pandas Docs and Pandas Source code of pandas to pass big CSV tables into my PostgreSQL DB in the fastest way possible.
Using pandas.DataFrame.to_sql using a Callable method "psql_insert_copy" seems the best solution so far.
But I don't understand how it works, honestly, I looked in several posts and I get that the pattern of arguments of this method 'table, conn, keys and data_iter' is fixed. I asked how the table is taking the "keys" along other person this post and this one.
Is it possible to pass along this method, or create another one, to pass columnames? so I could rename the columns inside the same callable method? This is because some column_names are not what I expect, and just this change will simplify my code.
(Also I want to learn more about how to customize my callable and how it works).
You can use this code example:
# STEP 0: Call libraries


# STEP 1:
# Setup the connection db engine

import csv
from io import StringIO

from sqlalchemy import create_engine

# STEP 2: Create the callable function/method
# Alternative to_sql() *method* for DBs that support COPY FROM
import csv
from io import StringIO

def psql_insert_copy(table, conn, keys, data_iter):
    """
    Execute SQL statement inserting data

    Parameters
    ----------
    table : pandas.io.sql.SQLTable
    conn : sqlalchemy.engine.Engine or sqlalchemy.engine.Connection
    keys : list of str
        Column names
    data_iter : Iterable that iterates the values to be inserted
    """
    # gets a DBAPI connection that can provide a cursor
    dbapi_conn = conn.connection
    with dbapi_conn.cursor() as cur:
        s_buf = StringIO()
        writer = csv.writer(s_buf)
        writer.writerows(data_iter)
        s_buf.seek(0)

        columns = ', '.join(['"{}"'.format(k) for k in keys])
        if table.schema:
            table_name = '{}.{}'.format(table.schema, table.name)
        else:
            table_name = table.name

        sql = 'COPY {} ({}) FROM STDIN WITH CSV'.format(
            table_name, columns)
        cur.copy_expert(sql=sql, file=s_buf)

## STEP 3 : Create the db connection (in my case I installed postgresql and connect to it
engine = create_engine('postgresql://myusername:mypassword@myhost:5432/mydatabase')



## STEP 4: Read my table "dummycsv.csv" from my project root folder 

df = pd.read_csv("dummycsv.csv")

## STEP 5: Pass this dummycsv data frame to the function "to_sql" with the argument, callable method. AND THE NEW COLUMNNAMES!

df.to_sql(name='dummycsv', schema='test', con=engine,if_exists="replace",  index=False, method=psql_insert_copy)

I try to add in this last function, and in the method an extra argument:
def psql_insert_copy(table, conn, keys, data_iter, colsrenamed)
.
.
.
# ...
df.to_sql(name='dummycsv', schema='test', con=engine,if_exists="replace",  index=False, method=psql_insert_copy, colsrenamed = listofstringswithnewnames):
.
.
.

Error I get when adding this new argument _colsrenamed _: TypeError: NDFrame.to_sql() got an unexpected keyword argument 'keys'
NOTE:
Also since this research took me quite a lot of time I considered:

to rename the table after using the function, using "ALTER TABLE tablename RENAME COLUMN ..." iteratively
Also I tried to change the "keys" argument (related with the column names in the psql_insert_copy function) by renaming the columns of the dataframe using df.rename(columns=dictionary_with_oldnames_and_newnames, inplace=True)

But these two approaches are bit buggy and requires more commit options and more steps could lead to more desynchronization of processes in my pipeline.

I can't really work out what this question is about. Of course you could wrap the to_sql method in your own function. Just rename the columns before you do the write?

Hi @roganjosh, have you tried this method before? Just try it. and later try to pass another argument (new column names) inside the callable function psql_insert_copy. if this works, could you explain how it works please? Many thanks

I had a go at answering but actually, on re-reading, your approach is (sorry to sound awful) a mess. Of course I can't pass another argument to psql_insert_copy without editing it first to take the extra argument. It really feels like you've cargo-culted this approach and then tried to work around what you've copy/pasted without really understanding how it works.

The example above does not have these modifications, but yes, I added to the function those arguments to make it work. I will update it. The issue remains the same:   df.to_sql(tablename, con=warehousedb, if_exists="replace", schema=schema_name, keys = list(df_valid_names["columnames"].keys()), index=False, method = psql_insert_copy) TypeError: NDFrame.to_sql() got an unexpected keyword argument 'keys'. Let me edit it

I'm trying to fix my answer up. It would be better not to edit at this point if you don't mind as I was trying to address things as they currently are

The extra argument it was already described (is "colsrenamed" )  in the original post.. I just added the error it got after adding this "extra argument".

Ok, I understand why you get the error, but you don't. And I think you're coming from R so there is way too much to try correct here. Pre writing it into a function, I gave an answer here that goes maybe 90% of the way, and you just need to package it up into a function. Forget about changing the arguments of pandas.to_sql - this is just a disaster. Make your own function with its own arguments and documentation

Thanks @roganjosh. I will try your method and if any success I will post my own method in a following post or this one edited.
